# Neatly checking if a nearby cell is empty

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix of cells (buttons in my case), if I click on one button, I need to check if a nearby (plus shape) cell is empty, and if a cell is empty (only one can be), I need to swap the two cells (the empty one and the clicked one).
What I do now is:

```
            if(j < 3)
                if (!fbarr[i, j + 1].Visible)
                    swap(fbarr[i, j], fbarr[i, j + 1]);
            if(j > 0)
                if (!fbarr[i, j - 1].Visible)
                    swap(fbarr[i, j], fbarr[i, j - 1]);
            if(i < 3)
                if (!fbarr[i + 1, j].Visible)
                    swap(fbarr[i, j], fbarr[i + 1, j]);
            if(i > 0)
                if (!fbarr[i - 1, j].Visible)
                    swap(fbarr[i, j], fbarr[i - 1, j]);
```

Now personally I think this is ugly as hell.
Is there a nicer way to do this? (This is C# if it matters)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current technique isn't necessarily bad, it just isn't DRY enough. You can also make the search space more explicit by getting the offsets into some kind of data structure. Here's an example using Tuples:

```
var offsets = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    Tuple.Create(0,  1),
    Tuple.Create(0, -1),
    Tuple.Create( 1, 0),
    Tuple.Create(-1, 0)
};

foreach (var offset in offsets) {
    int newI = i + offset.Item1;
    int newJ = j + offset.Item2;

    // New position must be within range
    if (newI >= 0 && newI <= 3 && newJ >= 0 && newJ <= 3) {
        if (!fbarr[newI, newJ].Visible) {
            swap(fbarr[i, j], fbarr[newI, newJ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do have only one if, but you also need to create each offset individually. So it's not ideal... But still better than my idea.

Comment: @shoham: True, but the benefit of listing the offsets individually is that it is very explicit and, arguably, easier to read. In addition, if you ever wanted to add diagonals to your search, it would be extremely easy. I'm sure that there are more "clever" ways of iterating through such offsets, but I don't think it is warranted in this case (keep in mind that cleverness is often at odds with maintainability - good code is simple).

Comment: @shoham: I think part of why it still might "look strange" is because C# as a language doesn't really make it very easy to just create and iterate through a set of constants. In a language like Python, for example, it's much easier to write an operation like this.